# Is OpenSSL FIPS Object Module fips validated for ARM64?

Tags: openssl

For OpenSSL FIPS Object Module  on http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/1401vend.htm

I don't see support for ARM64 / iOS 7, just ARM7 and ARMV7S

Does this mean that for ARM64 it isn't validated?

Comment: Probably best to ask this on the users list at www.openssl.org/support/community.html -- the people who actually work on OpenSSL FIPS hang out there and I haven't seen them here. Platforms are added from time to time by change letter and I don't think the publications are always updated immediately. Note the FIPS releases (final module code, user guide and policy docs) are free (beer) at www.openssl.org project, but FIPS development is done on (mostly?) paid basis at the overlapping but not identical www.openssl.com foundation.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to define "FIPS compliant" - there are a lot of FIPS standards, though by your link I assume you mean FIPS 140-2 in particular.  "Compliant" is not defined by NIST.  "Validated", however, is, and means that particular implementation will show up on the NIST site as having passed a particular level of FIPS 140-2 validation (Level 1 having the fewest requirements and Level 4 the most requirements to pass).

A more informative list than the one you referenced is at [NIST.gov Validated FIPS 140-1 and FIPS 140-2 Cryptographic Modules](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/1401val2013.htm) - you can see Samsung has walked an implementation through the validation process.

Per [OpenSSL's FIPS notes](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/fipsnotes.html), "OpenSSL itself is not validated, and never will be.  Instead a special carefully defined software component called the OpenSSL FIPS Object Module has been created. This Module was designed for compatibility with OpenSSL so that products using the OpenSSL API can be converted to use validated cryptography with minimal effort."

Start by reading the [OpenSSL FIPS User Guide](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide.pdf).